# Can't remove CAShapeLayer from Super Layer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to remove my circle that I've created as a CAShapeLayer and drawn with UIBezier path if I can't receive a measurement. In my (void)drawRect method for my UIView class, I create and draw a circle if a measurement is found. However, if there is no measurement I'd like to get rid of the circle. For some reason I can't.

Here is the code that creates the circle in -(void)drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CAShapeLayer *grayCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CAShapeLayer *progressArc = [CAShapeLayer layer];
DBHelper *dbHelper = [DBHelper getSharedInstance];

if ([dbHelper getPairedDevice]==nil) {
    [grayCircle removeFromSuperlayer]; // I want to remove the grayCirle if no measurement is found AKA getPairedDevice = nil
}

....

 if (_latestMeasurement) {

...

 // Gray outer circle
    UIBezierPath *grayCirclePath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
    grayCircle.path = [grayCirclePath CGPath];
    grayCircle.position = CGPointMake(realBounds.origin.x, realBounds.origin.y);
    grayCircle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    grayCircle.lineCap=kCALineCapRound;
    grayCircle.strokeColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    grayCircle.lineWidth = 30;

    // Progress arc
    UIBezierPath *progressPath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:patientOutput clockwise:YES];
    progressArc.path = [progressPath CGPath];
    progressArc.position = CGPointMake(grayCircle.frame.origin.x, grayCircle.frame.origin.y);
    progressArc.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    progressArc.lineCap=kCALineCapRound;
    progressArc.lineWidth = 30;

[self.layer addSublayer:grayCircle];
[self.layer addSublayer:progressArc];

}
```

So here's the issue: The following lines of code aren't removing the gray circle:

```
if ([dbHelper getPairedDevice]==nil) {
    [grayCircle removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

I'm wondering why is that the case, and how can I remove it from the view's sublayer?

Comment: There are two things going on here - is `getPairedDevice` definitely returning nil?

Comment: Yes most definitely

Comment: And when I try to access grayCircle in the if statement it returns null

Comment: yes - it will do, because you haven't initialised the **new** instance of it yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new reference to `grayCircle` each time you go through `drawRect`.  When you remove it - you're removing the new one, not the one you drew previously.

If you already have it, you need to find it first, then remove it - going through the subViews, or maintain a reference to it at the class level

Comment: Should I then create it as a property in my .h file and use that property throughout and hide it when necessary?

Comment: That would do it, yes.  Check that it's not nil before you remove it, and remove the definition from within `drawRect`

Comment: It seems to not be showing up at all. I merely added the circle as a property and then synthesized it in my .m

Comment: Ah @Russel I'm so sorry I just didn't inistialize it. I added grayCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer] and now it shows up

Comment: Yes it's been removed! Thank you so much!